# Create new database after deleting old Entity Framework generated database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I've created a simple context using a code-first approach with Entity Framework using the below connection string. All goes well and I find myself with a `.mdf` and `.ldf` file after running a test method.

```
"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=testdb;AttachDBFilename=Q:\Temp\testdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

For some reason I wish to delete this database. I try to look for the database in SSMS, but I can't find it. It is not registered under my databases. Now I feel I have 3 options:

1. Attach the database in SSMS and then delete it
2. Connect to the database in VS2015 Server Explorer by searching for the `.MDF` file and then deleting the database from VS.

   Add database via Server Explorer

   [image]

   Press to browse in SQL Server Object Explorer

   [image]

   Appears in Server Object Explorer where I can press delete

   [image]
3. Just delete the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files

All three methods remove the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

**HOWEVER**: when I start up the context again, I expect it to create the files again from scratch. however I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>
> The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   Cannot open database "testdb" requested by the login.
>
> The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-XXXXXXX\XXXXX'.

I feel I've deleted every reference to this database. I cannot find any other references. Yet somehow it appears there is one because it is trying to login rather than creating a new database.

Question: does anyone know how to address this issue? How can I properly delete the database + reference?

**UPDATE**:

In VS open connections during my test before deleting the file I see the following connection string.

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=Q:\Temp\testdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

However when exploring my Localdb in VS2015 there are no databases listed.

Comment: You have listed 2 different connection strings now. Which one are you using? .\SQLEXPRESS or localdb?

Comment: I am initializing with .\SQLEXPRESS. When using the acual connection to the database I've noticed the connection string being localdb.

Comment: in option 2 when you say connect to the database and delete it, are you connecting to .\SQLEXPRESS and deleting the db?

Comment: I've added the screenshots for option 2. I think it goes via the (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: Is user 'DESKTOP-XXXXXXX\XXXXX' a member of either the dbcreator server role or the sysadmin server role on the SQL server? What happens if you manually create an empty database and grant user 'DESKTOP-XXXXXXX\XXXXX' membership in the DB_Owner database role?

Comment: You'll probably have better results if you detach the db in SSMS before deleting the db. Than try running 'update-database' in the package manager, after deleting the db (2) files. Add a login for the user (if it doesn't already exists) in SSMS, and assign the login as the db owner (also in SSMS) before running the app. Also, you can change the default to SQLEXPRESS in VS tools instead of using the localdb, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicit initialization of your Db with with Db initialization strategy `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`. Something along the lines of ..

```
public class YourDBContext: DbContext 
{

        public YourDBContext(): base("YourDBContextConnStr") 
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDBContext>());

        }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I've added the initialization strategy. The error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Being triggered by the fact that I initialized using ".\SQLEXPRESS" and EF changed it to "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" I've changed the connectionstring.

```
"data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=testdb;AttachDBFilename=Q:\Temp\testdb.mdf");
```

Et voila. Using the SQL Express LocalDB in my connectionstring as a datasource I can now mindlessly delete and recreate databases. Further more the databases now correctly show up in my SQL Server Object Explorer under LocalDb (instead of not showing up anywhere at all).

I still dont know why it could initially create with the ".\SQLEXPRESS" connectionstring but not re-create. As if it was somewhere hiding the information that the .mdf database exists and was always trying to reconnect to it.